# why is JHipster JDL only generating strings values for Enum expressions for angular/typescript code?

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster, jdl

Not sure if this is a bug in JDL, or if I'm just not understanding it, but if I create an enum in Jhipster JDL like this

```
enum PricingModel {
    AVAILABILITY,   
    DEADLINES,     
    PAYMENTS        
}
```

Then it will generate this typescript for my angular code.

```
export const enum PricingModel {
    'AVAILABILITY',
    'DEADLINES',
    'PAYMENTS'
}
```

Unless I am doing the switch statement wrong... this switch statement will not work:

To fix it I propose that the generated code from JhipsterJDL be changed to generate something like this ad defined in Typescript 2.4 :

```
export const enum PricingModel {
    AVAILABILITY = 'AVAILABILITY',
    DEADLINES = 'DEADLINES',
    PAYMENTS ='PAYMENTS',
}
```

Comment: the swtich statement that does not work with JDL generated code:     switch (offering.pricingModel) {
            case PricingModel.DEADLINES:
                *wont' get here
            case default:
                * only this happens
    }

Comment: This was fixed in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/7557

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I'm glad to I'm catching on to the great work you do!  I'll be helping out one day... still got some learning to do